# Finding locales with no separate entry in /usr/share/locale on Debian

Tags: debian, dpkg, locale

I want to remove all unneeded locales on my `Debian` system in `/usr/share/locale`. I have installed the package `locales` and generated `en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8` by using

```
echo "en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
locale.gen
```

Now I would like to delete every locale that is not needed in `/usr/share/locale` by editing `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes`. However, in order to be able to do this I need to know which entries in e.g. `/usr/share/locale` need to be preserved. Where are locales which do not have a separate entry in `/usr/share/locale/` such as `en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8` located in `/usr/share/locale/`? E.g. Is `en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8` identical to `en_GB`?

Comment: Why do you want to remove files under `/usr`? They'll come back at the next upgrade of the package (and locales are part of the libc package, so they get pretty frequent security upgrades).

Comment: It's for usage in a Dockerfile. But I found a different solution using the `exclude` file of `dpkg`. I just wanted to wait for other users to give an answer.